# Suspend all threads of a Linux program using a signal

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

During the development of a profiling framework I ran into the following problem, that I need to suspend all running threads (including the main thread) if the program receives a signal (namely SIGUSR1 for example) and I am interested if there is a possibility of the following workflow can be implemented on Linux/POSIX systems:

Overload the signal-handler for SIGUSR1 which does:

1. It suspends all running threads of the program, but we do not have access to a list of pids or similar information. Even not if the threads directly used via pthreads or if they are OpenMP instances.
2. Write all collected data to the disc (Their origin is not of interest here). But the write process influence some runtime data collected by the profiling and for this reason all threads need to be stopped.
3. After writing the profiling data continue all threads.

The stuff I read so far about the thread-signal handling was that if a signal is sent to a process an arbitrary thread of the program will handle the signal. But this does not help me.

Comment: You can send a signal to a whole process group by sending it to pid `-pgrp`.

Comment: ...you have just finished suspending all the running threads, (somehow) but, by that time, other threads have been made running:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about it the wrong way.

Even if you, somehow, managed to suspend all threads using a single signal (which you can, just use `SIGSTOP`), you couldn't do what you're trying to do.

What you are trying to do is called a "global snapshot". You want to dump the thread's state in a *consistent* way. The problem with a signal is that, in all likelihood, it will catch some threads mid-calculation. It is unlikely that you structured each thread's activity so that it has consistent data in memory in each and every nanosecond of execution.

Nor should you. Such a structuring is insanely hard, and yields no benefits.

Instead, you should create a dump of the data as *it might have* been. This means you do not need for the dump to actually represent a moment in time during your program's execution. It just needs to represent a state your program *might* have been in.

The best way to do that, IMHO, is to inline the code of the snapshot into each thread's code. Use a signal to set a variable saying a snapshot is needed, and then have each thread suspend itself when its internal data is consistent and ready for snapshot.

Comment: Your last idea sounds like something to think of. The reason why I came up with the above idea was that each thread collections its profile data in one single global buffer and if this is full the thread writes the whole buffer to disc. But this write effects the eventually ongoing computation inside the other threads and in this way disturbs the measurements. The idea with the global suspend was to set an indicator that a write was going on an that the runtime data of the profiling is corrupted by this.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu I'm fairly sure your implementation has a bug. Several threads writing to one buffer have so many edge cases, I would never go about doing it. How do you synchronize where to write to? How do you make sure that the cells supposedly full actually have the data they should have?

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu a better approach, IMO, is to have each thread write the data to their own buffer, and then collect it when you want to dump.

Comment: The buffer to collect the data is locked using a mutex so there is no problem with race condition on writing the data. The problem is we do not know a priory who many threads there will be, be cause we integrate the profiling via an LD_PRELOAD like procedure. Having each thread a own buffer will in some cases lead to a too high memory consumption if there are many threads.

Comment: If you interrupt with a signal, what's guaranteeing that the global buffer has consistent data? After all, the thread holding the lock may be in the middle of an update. Also, if you're holding a lock, you don't need to freeze all threads. Just acquire the lock. Lastly, if you have a single lock everyone has to take, what do you gain from many threads?

Comment: The lock is only held for a short moment of time where the profile data is written to the global buffer. But when the buffer is full the thread which fills the buffer also writes it. During this operation other threads are busy and their runtime might get disturbed by the write operation and therefore I need this construction, that we can at least indicate that a write operation disturbed the remaining workload.